# TSQL OVER CLAUSE That has no partition by has Order By clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window, partitioning, clause

I am having problems reading code like

```
SELECT 
    employeeID as ID,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG (Salary) DESC) AS Value 
FROM Salaries
```

which supposedly gets the average salary of every employees

My understanding is the code should be

```
SELECT 
    employeeID as ID,
    RANK() OVER (Partition By employeeID ORDER BY AVG (Salary) DESC) AS Value 
FROM Salaries
```

but the above code works just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is not working for me (returning *Msg 8120
Column 'Salaries.employeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*), until I add `group by employeeID`:

```
SELECT 
    employeeID as ID,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG (Salary) DESC) AS Value 
FROM Salaries
GROUP BY employeeID
```

Perhaps, for better understanding, it can be rewritten equivalently as:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT employeeID, AVG (Salary) as AvgSalary
    FROM Salaries
    GROUP BY employeeID
)
select employeeID as ID
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AvgSalary DESC) as Value
    --, AvgSalary
from cte
```

In this case, average salary by employee is calculated in the CTE, and then query is extended with ranking column `Value`. Adding `partition by employeeID` to over clause:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT employeeID, AVG (Salary) as AvgSalary
    FROM Salaries
    GROUP BY employeeID
)
select employeeID as ID
    , RANK() OVER (partition by employeeID ORDER BY AvgSalary DESC) as Value
    --, AvgSalary
from cte
```

will lead to `Value = 1` for every row in the result set (which is not what seem attempted to be achieved), because of `rank()` will reset numbering to 1 for each distinct `employeeID`, and `employeeID` is distinct in every row, since data was aggregated by this column prior to ranking.